# Inserting images in R markdown using a path variable

Tags: r, variables, r-markdown

I am new to R and Rmd and trying to generate a report using Rmd. This report has several images inserted along with the text. I am able to insert an image by hardcoding the path of the image. I have no problems with that but I need the path as a variable because it varies with the project. Can anyone help me with the syntax for calling a variable within a path to the image?

```
![Relatedness check](/data/array_processing/in_progress/Project123/files/data/plots/Project123.ibd.png)
```

"**Project123**" changes based on the project. Is there a way I can declare this variable and call it to define the path?

Help please.

Comment: In Rmd files, one can use inline code (even in image paths), so perhaps `![Relatedness](\`r imgpath\`)` (where `imgpath` is a variable in R that you defined to be your `/data/array.../file.png` path/filename).

Comment: @r2evans could you submit your answer as an answer so that Suresh can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images can use online R code for dynamic paths and/or alt text. (Early adopters of rmarkdown often tried this method as the default method of including R plots in the reports, using `png(filepath...); plot(...); dev.off()` followed by what I recommend you use.)

This will allow you to do what you need:

```
![something meaningful](`r filepath`)
```

as raw markdown (and not inside a traditional code chunk).

If you aren't familiar with inline code blocks, then know that you can put just about anything in an inline code block. This is handy for including dynamic content in a paragraph of text, for example "the variance of the sample is `\`r var(sample(99))``". (Often it is just a pre-created variable, if numeric it is often rounded or `format`ed to control the display of significant figures.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I couldn't figure out how to accept yday. Done.